# Continuous Message as long as EditText is being used

Tags: java, android, timer, android-edittext

We're trying to implement a "The User is typing" message as long as a user keeps typing within a specific EditText. For example, once the user starts typing within the EditText, and as long as 2 seconds didn't pass since the last typing event, keep showing the "User is typing" message.

Any idea how to achieve that easily without blocking any threads?

Thanks!
Yohay

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it by using focusChangeListener

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            //user typing
        } else {
            //user stop typing
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But this solution means that the message will sustain even if the user is not actually typing anything ...

Comment: if boolean hasFocus equal false , remove your message

Comment: The EditText can have focus without the user actually ever typing anything, so the message will keep showing.

Comment: try to using textwatcher

Answer (score 0):

Once user start typing , start a background thread(`BT`) and pass `text` of your `edit text` via `Message` to your `BT`. After every 2 seconds ping (post a `message`) to your `Main Thread` from `BT`. On receiving the `message` in `MainThread` pass a `message` containing `text` in your `edit text`  to your `BT`. On receiving `message` in `BT` simply compare `text` just received to `previous text passed` in `BT`. If both the `texts` are same, user is not typing.
But user can start typing again any moment, so keep on playing this game in background until message is alive(neither sent nor discarded). Once message life is over kill your `BT`.

Edit example code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private boolean killThread = false;
private EditText editText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFocusChange: gained focus");
                startThread(new WeakReference<MainActivity>(MainActivity.this));
            }
        }
    });

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // for simplicity killing thread here
            killThread = true;
        }
    });
}

private void startThread(final WeakReference<MainActivity> activityWeakReference) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        String savedText = "";

        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
                if (null == activity) {
                    // Activity destroyed, killME!!!
                    killThread = true;
                    Log.e(TAG, "run: activity reference null, killing MYSELF");
                } else {
                    if (savedText.equals(activity.editText.getText().toString())) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: user is not typing");
                    } else {
                        savedText = activity.editText.getText().toString();
                        Log.e(TAG, "run: user typing ");

                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } while (!killThread);
        }
    }).start();

}
```

}

When `EditText` gains focus , I am starting a Thread (passing `WeakReference` to `Activity` also) and then using `WeakReference` getting hold of `EditText` and checking its `Text`. For Simplicity, I am simply killing `Thread` on `Button Click`.

Comment: Interesting. Not sure I follow though - can you show a conceptual snippet to demonstrate this?